# To Update People picker field in DataSheet view in SharePoint 2010

Tags: people-picker

On updating the People picker field from the datasheet view of SP 2010, the following error is generated:

[image]

Please assit how to proceed with this.

Comment: Wich field are you trying to update?

Comment: Contact selector or people picker field

Comment: And wich other fields are in the view?